Calling git command in Azure Pipeline Powershell writes no output
In an Azure Pipeline I want to run git diff-tree on the commits in the push that triggered the pipeline. In a Powershell task and using the Azure DevOps Services REST API I am able to get all the commit IDs for the current push.
Then, in that task I run & git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $commitId -r, but I get no output from this command.
I have tried to call it in various ways:
$files = @()
foreach ($commitId in $commitIds)
{
  Write-Host "Commit id: $commitId"
  $files += @(& git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $commitId -r)
  Write-Host "Last exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
}

$files = @()
foreach ($commitId in $commitIds)
{
  Write-Host "Commit id: $commitId"
  & git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $commitId -r > "$commitId.txt"
  Write-Host "Last exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
  $files += @(Get-Content "$commitId.txt")
}

$files = @()
foreach ($commitId in $commitIds)
{
  Write-Host "Commit id: $commitId"
  $files += @(Invoke-Expression "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $commitId -r")
  Write-Host "Last exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
}

All of these work locally, but when run in the Azure Pipeline it seems like nothing happens. $LASTEXITCODE is always 0. Why does this not work?

Probably the repository is a shallow clone that does not contain more than the head commit. Se this question for how unshallow.

Yep, that was it. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it.

git diff-tree command requires at least depth 2 to get the changed files.
The cause of the issue is related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.
By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is 1 by default. Refer to this doc: Shallow fetch

New pipelines created after the September 2022 Azure DevOps sprint 209 update have Shallow fetch enabled by default and configured with a depth of 1. Previously the default was not to shallow fetch.

You can try to set the fetchDepth to 0 or >2 in YAML Pipeline.
For example:
YAML Pipeline:
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0

Classic Pipeline:

